# How to know if a class is clicked in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, click, addeventlistener

I searched and tried multiple time but it is not working. I have this website: https://store.longphuong.vn/ which I wanna write a function to return true if a "cart icon" is clicked and false if it is not. I tried to test it online by writing function on console:

1/ Attempt 1:

```
var result=false; test=document.querySelector(".cart-img-icon"); test.addEventListener('click',function testfunction(){result=true;});console.log(result);
```

=> Always shows "false" after I click "cart icon".

2/ Attempt 2:

```
var result=false; test=document.getElementsByClassName("cart-img-icon")[0]; test.addEventListener('click',function testfunction(){result=true;});console.log(result);
```

=> Always shows "false" after I click "cart icon".

I just want console.log(result) shows "True". Please help me if you have any idea. Thank you all!

Comment: You need to remove `console.log(result)` inside the `addEventListener` method

Comment: Hi @lucumt, thanks so much for helping me. I tried your code below and it really shows "true". However, my idea is that var result will still remain the value "true" after we addEventListener. Because eventually, I need the result as true or false correctly (I need to write customer javascript in google tag manager with a function return true to trigger a tag). I tried your code but it is still return "false". Do you have any more idea for this?

Comment: Then you need to bind hover event,to make `result` reset to false after the click finished

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment,you neeed to move `console.log(result)` inside the `addEventListener` function

More detail explanation can be found at below code

```js
var result=false; 
var test=document.querySelector(".cart-img-icon"); 
test.addEventListener('click',function testfunction(){
  result=true;
  console.log(result);// need to output at this position
});

// in this case,console.log will print immediately once the code is loaed,even if we do not click it
//console.log(result);
```

```html
<button class='cart-img-icon'>Button</button>
```